# how to use ImageDataGenerator for semantic segmentation labels?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, semantic-segmentation

I'm performing semantic segmentation and I would like to use the ImageDataGenerator class to augment my data. On the keras docs I read about using a generator for the image as well as for the masks however, I was wondering how this would work? My labels are integer values and the .fit throws an error as it expects a rank of 4 and my shape was (1605, 96, 160), so I converted the labels to be one hot encoded to give the shape of (1605, 96, 160, 4).

This is my code for augmentaion:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
data_gen_args = dict(featurewise_center=True,
                     featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                     rotation_range=5,
                     width_shift_range=0.1,
                     height_shift_range=0.1,
                     zoom_range=0.2,
                     brightness_range=[0.5,1.5],
                     horizontal_flip=True)
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

# Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the fit and flow methods
image_datagen.fit(X_org, augment=True, seed=seed)
mask_datagen.fit(Y_org, augment=True, seed=seed)

image_generator = image_datagen.flow(
    X_train,
    seed=seed,
    batch_size=32)

mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow(
    Y_train,
    seed=seed,
    batch_size=32)

train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
```

Since the same functions are called on the images and labels I was wondering how augmentations such as brightening and featurewise_center would effect the labels. Would it apply the standardization on the class labels and change the class value? Do I have to call .fit and .flow methods for the labels?